# We're trying to assign the ACCOUNTADMIN role to a user but for some reason it doesn't seem to be taking effect or updating..not sure why?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're trying to assign a user the role of ACCOUNTADMIN but even after updating the user with the ACCOUNTADMIN role it doesn't seem to be updating for the user.

Does it take a while for roles to be picked up and updated?

The user we'd like to be set ACCOUNTADMIN looks like they have the right setup in the config tables but we aren't having any luck.

Comment: If you run "SHOW GRANTS TO USER <user_name>" does it show that the user has the ACCOUNTADMIN role? If it does, has that user tried logging out of Snowflake and then logging back in?

Comment: With what role are you trying to do the operation? And does the output show "success" when granting the role to this user?

Comment: show grants of role accountadmin; The statement would show you if the role has been granted to the user or not. If the username doesn't appear then - you have to run, grant role accountadmin to user <username>;

Answer (score 1):

> Does it take a while for roles to be picked up and updated?

No, it does not take time.

When you grant a new role to a user, the user will still use the default role. You may check it using the describe command (look at the DEFAULT_ROLE value):

```
describe user yourusername;
```

Have you tried to switch to the account admin role?

```
use role accountadmin;
```

You may also set the account admin as the default role for the user:

```
alter user yourusername set DEFAULT_ROLE = accountadmin;
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but, seeing as though I'm here: It's not good practice to default to account admin. It's the Snowflake version of logging in with SUDO